# ¿Como puedo obtener el próximo valor de mi campo auto_incrementable?

Tags: php, android-studio, webservice, autoincremento

**Descripción:**

Estoy programando mis webservices con mysqli y php para mi app en Android Studio. Necesito obtener el próximo valor que se generaría en mi campo "id_publicacion" que es de tipo int, primary key y auto incrementable.

**¿Cuál es el problema?**

En la tabla "publicaciones" de mi base de datos hay, POR EJEMPLO, 5 filas cuyos "id_publicacion" son 1, 2, 3, 4 y 5. Luego, podría generar 20 filas más cuyos "id_publicacion" seran el 6, 7, 8, 9, 10......y 25.

Si yo decido borrar las filas 6-25, seguiría teniendo 5 filas con "id_publicacion" 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Acá el problema: yo quiero obtener el próximo número de mi id auto incrementable, el cual no sería 6 porque ya fue generado, sino que sería el 26.

**Pregunta final**

¿Como puedo obtener el próximo valor de mi campo auto_incrementable ("id_publicacion") que en este caso sería el número 26 y no el 6?

**Adjunto el código que intenté usar para mi WEB SERVICE en php**

```
<?PHP
$hostname_localhost="CENSURADO";
$database_localhost="CENSURADO";
$username_localhost="CENSURADO";
$password_localhost="CENSURADO";

$json=array();

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

    $consulta="select id_publicacion from publicaciones order by id_publicacion desc limit 1";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        
    if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $result["id_publicacion"]=$registro['id_publicacion'];
        $json['datos'][]=$result;
    }else{
        $resultar["id_publicacion"]=0;
        $json['datos'][]=$resultar;
    }
    
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

**Breve explicación del código php:**

Básicamente este web service devuelve un JSON con el valor que le sigue **A LA ULTIMA FILA** de mi id auto_incrementable. Para el ejemplo dado anteriormente, el json retornaría un valor "6" lo cual no es lo que busco, por lo que repito, quisiera que devuelva (en este caso) el valor "26".

**Muchas gracias por leer**

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, el autoincrementsl no se reinicia porque borres filas. Si borras las filas de 6 a 25, el siguiente autoincremental es el 26, automáticamente.

Comment: Hola y gracias por responder. Expliqué eso mismo a lo largo de toda mi publicacion ._.

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer eso?. Parece no tener caso, y si hubiera una justificación no deberías usar `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Si es por una cuestión cosmética, es más fácil generar los números secuencialmente al momento de mostrar los datos.

Answer (score 2):

Ya pude resolverlo. Lo que busco me lo da el resultado de esta consulta:

```
$consulta="select AUTO_INCREMENT from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'nombre_de_la_base_de_datos' and table_name = 'nombre_de_la_tabla';
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) en tu sentencia SQL.

O puedes usar el metodo [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) para obtenerlo en php.

Te dejo los enlaces a las documentaciones oficiales.

Comment: Hola y muchas gracias por responder. Probé haciendo una consulta desde php my admin a my tabla. "select last_insert_id();" . No funcionó. Devolvió un valor "0" :(. Por lo que entendí de last_insert_id(), este solo sirve si se ejecuta justo después de agregar una fila a la tabla. Yo necesito que funcione cuando yo quiera, es decir sin necesidad de insertar una fila o datos previamente